# Open Mapping Theorem: reversely bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Is it true that an open linear map necessarily is reversely bounded, i.e.: $c \lVert x\rVert\leq \lVert T x\rVert$
If so how to proof **without** the existence of an inverse?

Comment: No. Take any non-injective, bounded, onto map between Banach spaces. Such as the left shift operator on $\ell_2$.

Comment: Ah, right, thanks!

Comment: A characterization of being bounded below is given in Abramovich and Aliprantis, An Invitation to Operator Theory, Theorem 2.5: A bounded operator between Banach spaces is bounded below iff it is injective and has closed range. That is a nice application of the open mapping theorem answering the question on the open mapping theorem itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T$ is an open map, then we have that $T(B_r)=U$ is open and contains $0$ (where $B_r=\{x:\|x\|<r\}$), and thus contains some ball $B_s$, for some $s>0$. If the map is injective, then $Tx\in X\backslash T(B_{\|x\|/2})\subseteq X\backslash B_c$ for some $c$, which you can show can be taken to be independent of $x$ by linearity.

If your Banach space $X$ is finite-dimensional (and over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$), then the [invariance of dimension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) tells you that if $T$ is open then it must be an isomorphism.

However if $X$ is infinite dimensional, I think you can find open, **non-injective** mappings, and such maps are obviously not reversely bounded. I'll let you know if I find a counterexample.

**Edit:** As @DavidMitra commented, the left-shift operator on $\ell^2$ is such an open, non-injective mapping.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that an open linear map necessarily is reversely bounded, i.e.: $c \|x\| ≤ \|Tx\|$

No. Let $T$  be   the projection of $\mathbb R^2$   onto $\mathbb R$ defined by $T(x,y)=x$. Set $z=x+iy$.  It is clear that $c \lvert z\rvert \leq \lvert x\rvert$   does not hold.

It seems that  we can  define a branch  $R$  of $T^{-1}$  such that  $\lvert Ry\rvert \leq c \lvert y\rvert$.

Comment: Simple and enlightening. Thank you! :)